# Which tank fills up first?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

Which tank would fill first. My first guess was 3 and 4 simultaneously due to Pascal's Law of pressure distribution. Then tank 2 and then 1. Could you please help? This is my first question ever on Stack Exchange.

[image: Which tank fills first?]

Comment: Is 2 to 3 pipe supposed to be black there?

Comment: Ouch yea... Didn't see that there... It's why my answer was wrong. So with the block between 2 and 3... Tank 2 fills up first.

Comment: Other wise 3,4 together... Then 2...then 1... According to the laws of Physics...

Comment: I know this has been asked before when it first made rounds on reddit, but I guess the others have been closed and deleted since.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Googling your title produces [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RId3Ah-rm9kto) as #2. There is also a video solution at #1 but it is rather dull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tank 1 will to the level of the pipe. Then water will flow into 2.

If the pipe is blocked, 2 will fill. When the water in 2 reaches the level of the upper pipe, tanks 1 and 2 will stay even with each other. When tank 2 reaches the top, water will spill out. It ends there.

If the pipe to 2 is open, tank 2 will fill to the level of the lower pipe. Then water will flow into 3. Water in tank 3 will stay even with the level in the pipe to 4.

It looks like the level of the upper part of both pipes from 3 are the same. When the level in 3 rises to the pipes, water will begin to spill into 4. When 4 is full up to the pipe, the level will rise in 2, 3, and 4 until it spills over the top of 3 and 4.

Comment: Tank 4 will start filling only after level of water in 3 gets up to the level of input pipe of tank 4.

Comment: @Ruslan - Yes. I guess I wasn't clear.